# Azure Hyperledger Fabric : Interacting with the network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a HyperLedger Fabric setup on Azure. I have spun-up the ready made software on the Azure. It has installed 4 machines peer0, peer1, ca & orderer.

Now where do i install the Composer software on? Do i need to spin up a new machine just for the composer or it should be installed on one of those 4 machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to install Fabric Composer on any of those machines.  You should be able to run Composer locally and then just specify the correct endpoints in the connection profile in order to interact with the nodes deployed on Azure.
If you are looking to deploy Composer in the Azure, then yes, I'd suggest using a separate Azure VM / container for it

Comment: Hi Gari, thank you for your reply. I am trying to build on what you've replied earlier. I have deployed a linux server and installed composer on it as per the documentation in [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html). It was accomplished by SSH'ing into that linux server using a windows machine. Now opened composer i've installed on linux using a chrome browser on windows machine.  I am able to see the composer UI. I see "Create Business Network Card". Tried to create a card but unable to. Could you please help me with some documentation or steps?